# Simple Interest: Finding Annuity

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question is as follows:

Johnny owns an annuity that provides him with payments at the end of every two months, beginning on February 28, 2010. The first three payments are \$75 each, the next six payments are \$50 each, and the last three payments are \$25 each. Assume that the interest rate is $i^{(6)} = 12\%$ throughout the term of the annuity. After the final annuity payment, the interest rate changes to $i^{(6)} = 8\%$. Find the value of the annuity on June 30, 2013.

I am not sure how to use $i^{(6)}$, it is interest for 6 months? and then we double it to find for 12 months? Any help is much appreciated.

TIA

Anmol

Answer (score 0):

$i^{(m)}$ is the nominal interest rate, convertible $m$ times in a year. So for $i^{(6)}$, it represents interest collected 6 times in a year - every two months. Since interest is compounding - it is not a simple matter of multiplying by 6 to get the annual effective interest rate

The relation between the two is as follows -

$$i^ = \left(1 + \frac{i^{(m)}}{12}\right)^m$$